# For loop to produce a series of dataframes in output based on a criteria

Tags: r, for-loop

I have gleamed from existing somewhat similar questions that 1) for loops are slow and 2) outputting to a list and then making a dataframe is preferable to outputting directly to a dataframe.

Nonetheless:
So I have a bunch of NIBRS/UCR (Incident-Based Uniform Crime Reporting) data.  I want to create 50 new lists/dataframes/tables, each segregating the data by state.

Data is:

```
Date   CrimeDataField1  CDF2  CDF3   etc   State.Abbrev.
xxx          xxx         xxx   xxx   xxx       xxx
```

My clumsy attempt at a for loop:

```
for(i in unique(State.Abbrev.)){
+ i.allyrs<-HCtest1[State.Abbrev.=="i",]}
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I should add that the goal here is that each new dataframe of data-by-state should ideally be named AbbreviationforthatState.allyrs, and I wanted to take care of both the output and naming in this manner via my single for loop.  Maybe not intelligent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `split` function:

```
x = data.frame(num = 1:26, let = letters, LET = LETTERS)
set.seed(1)
split(x, sample(rep(1:2, 13)))
split(x, x$let)
```

In your case probably

```
list_of_dfs = split(HCtest1,HCtest1$State.Abbrev.)
```

By the way, for loops aren't bad as such it is extending data within for loops that is bad. If you can pre-allocate then it is not that bad (just not as nice looking).

Have a look at the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) which will give you insight into R's method of working (it is copy on change) and given that you are starting out [this link](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/10-R-packages-I-wish-I-knew-about-earlier.html).

Edit: To name your list:

```
names(list_of_dfs) = paste("MyName",1:length(list_of_dfs),sep="*")
```

Comment: list_of_dfs = split(HCtest1,HCtest1$State.Abbrev.)

 gives me a list of all the data, in state order.

In a function or for loop, how do I name the output dataframes based on "i" within the loop/function?  Ideally, I want the function to cycle through AL, AK, AR, and give me new dataframes named "AL.allyrs", "AK.allyrs" etc, through referencing "i."  

In a for loop, what is proper syntax for referring to each "i", which is in this case each unique State.Abbrev., for both 1) pulling data within HCtest1 that only applies to each i, and 2) naming each output frame by "[i].allyrs"?

Comment: I tried this, I will see if it works, but it is going to take forever.  

    for(i in State.Abbrev.){
    + state<-HCtest1[State.Abbrev. == i,]
    + names<-paste("allyrs",i,sep="")
    + assign(names,state)}  

I'm sorry - CTRL+K doesn't seem to indent and format code for me?  It goes gray, then reverts when I save edits.

Comment: how do I name the output dataframes based on "i" within the loop/function: `list_of_dfs = split(HCtest1,HCtest1$State.Abbrev.); names(list_of_dfs) = paste("MyName",1:length(list_of_dfs),sep="*")`.

Comment: Ah...that is much faster than what I did, (which also works, and is proof why the Inferno and ddply would be preferable).  Instead of what I pasted in 2nd comment, I did:    

     for(i in unique(State.Abbrev.)) 

(Rest of code in 2nd comment the same).  I apologize for how clumsy I am on here, but whenever I try to do code indentation in a comment, it doesn't work (and neither does any other formatting)...I looked up a link on Stack that gives some additional guidelines but I'm still not doing it correctly, I guess taking the question down that tangent is also frowned upon.